# Should I use ListView to show sms inside inbox?

Tags: android, listview, sms

So I'm writing an application to send/receive/read sms messages. I looked up some tutorials and noticed all of them use ListView to list messages. Is there no other(better) way to do it? I'm aiming at android 6, so I know it's not the most fresh release, but still. Should I just use ListView and add some styling to distinct sms received and sent? Is that how native(or other advanced) SMS application work? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use Recycler View instead https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Comment: Is RecyclerView an answer? It's described "RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView." here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html 

@ShylendraMadda Thank You, Didn't notice your comment before posting mine :)

Comment: Yeah true, as it described above "It is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use RecyclerView, which is far more advanced and customize-able than ListView.

Here is a link to start with: http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/

Note: I'm not representing or related to hmkcode in any way, nor intend to promote hmkcode on any forum this is just a link to provide something to start with.